# MVC View Model returning NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm creating my first MVC application with the entity framework involved but experiencing a bit of an odd issue.

I'm just creating a simple view which brings a Model which contains some basic SQL SP results but as a return the view the Model is returning null so giving me a "Object refrence" error. The error comes to no surprise because obviously if Model returns null, there is no object but I can execute the SP in SSMS with no issue and get the return values expected.

Here is my Code if you would like to see:

CONTROLLER

```
 public class ColorController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ColorsMainEntities empdb = new ColorsMainEntities();

        return View(empdb.GetColors(0,""));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string customerName)
    {
        ColorsMainEntities empdb = new ColorsMainEntities();
        return View(empdb.GetColors(0,""));
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<Colors_Test.M_Colors>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Colors</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Color", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <span>Customer Name:</span> @Html.TextBox("CustomerName")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        <br />
       <br />
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>RGBA</th>
                <th>Hex</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (M_Colors color in Model)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>@color.ColorID</td>
            <td>@color.Color</td>
            <td>@color.Category</td>
            <td>@color.Type</td>
            <td>@color.RGBA</td>
            <td>@color.Hex</td>
        </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetColors] (@pnColorID INT = 0, @pcColor VARCHAR(999) = '')
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@pcColor <> '')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM M_Colors WHERE Color LIKE '%' + @pcColor + '%'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM M_Colors
    END

END
```

[image: EF Function Import]

Any help is appreciated, been going at this debugging for quite some time.

My one concern on theory is that the Entity framework returns an ObjectResult instead of a IEnumerable but that would cause a error on that conversion attempt. Unfortunately I can't get my controller level code to hit break points therefore I can't confirm that.

Comment: Could you share how the SP is called in EF?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited the SP in the question

Comment: @AT-2017 Sorry I just realized I misread your statement, I'll add a screenshot to show the EF settings but all it's doing is using the EF function call to execute the SP if I'm correct.

Comment: put the debugger into your index() method and check if you are getting any result from the SP. you can do something like this var result = empdb.GetColors(0,"");

Answer (score 0):

first call would be to debug your own code and see what's going on.
Stop doing one liners like this :

```
return View(empdb.GetColors(0,""));
```

instead, separate the code like this:

```
var colors = empdb.GetColors(0,"");

//some extra checks here, decide what you do if there are no colors returns, 
//maybe return an empty list for example so you don't get null errors any more.

return View(colors);
```

now you can put a breakpoint on the colors line, and see what your repo returns.

You can step into the repo code to see what's going. You can do that with your code as well, you could put a breakpoint on the return statement and when you stop there step into the code again, however it's a lot easier if you stay away from those nasty one liners.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in my message I explain for some reason I can't get breakpoints to hit my controller what so ever which I've spent much time trying to figure that out as well. I've looked at many solutions for others and discussions and can't find an answer on that on either. As soon as I figure out a solution to that, I will try this for sure.

Comment: Actually looking into it further, I am able to hit breakpoints but instead my BeginForm command is just NOT hitting the controller what so ever, atleast from what I understand. Does my beginform look proper to you? I appreciate any help of course, in a bit of a struggle.